# Regex for script tags with no text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will identify all script tags shaped like:

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

It's important that it only finds tags with a src attribute and without any text between the  tag and the  tag, unless it's just spaces.

Identify:

```
 <script src=".." -OTHER ATTRIBUTES- >-EMPTY OR SPACES-</script>
```

Do not identify:

```
<script></script>
<script src="...">COMMENT</script>
<script src="..."/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Just to clarify: you do want to use regexp instead of more convenient DOM API?

Answer (score 0):

Although you shouldn't use regex to parse html (there is a famous answer I am sure someone will link to explaining why in detail), to answer your question anyway, you could do...

```
/<script src=".+?"[^>]*?>\s*<\/script>/g
```

Live demo: https://regexr.com/3htsa

Key elements...

```
.+?       any character, one or more times, un-greedily
[^>]*?    any character that is not a >, zero or more times, un-greedily
\s*       whitespace characters, zero or more times
```

Comment: Won't work if any attribute is present before `src`.

Comment: This is a pretty nice start to help me get started, thanks! I fixed the case where an attribute can also be before the src tag as pointed out by  PJProudhon.

However, I noticed that it's not working for this example:

<script src="..."><xslt>COMMENT</xslt></script>

It's selecting although it should not. Any tips here please?

Comment: @PietSmet although it feels like you are close to a solution, you should not try to parse xml with regular expressions, xml is not a regular language: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/665261

Comment: Hi Billy, that's true, thank you for the info.

I'm indeed close to a solution, I just need to make sure the regex doesn't select any '>' except for the first one as seen in "<script >".

Anyone have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @PietSmet I updated it for you, but as I say, this is the wrong approach and will cause you more trouble than it's worth - parser is the correct answer

Comment: @PietSmet assuming you are not running in browser, I recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio which has jQuery like syntax for manipulating html/xml